# How can I supervise an akka-Http HttpApp server?

Tags: akka, akka-http, akka-supervision

I have a akka ActorSystem with some features and I use akka-http server (HttpApp) as an endpoint. This http server provide some services to legacy users that are not implemented with akka.
I want to supervise this HttpApp server  in order to manage restarts and so on.
Therefore I need to know when HttpServer stops or crash in order to react and restart this http endpoint.
How can I supervise an akka-Http HttpApp server?